# where do I put the distinct in in my code?

Tags: sql, function, distinct

I have the following sql code:

```
select upper(regexp_substr(street1, '\S+$'))
```

but I don't know where I should put the distinct keyword to have unique values in the table, because I prints out many duplicate values.

---

Edit - from comments below.

Complete Query(error):

```
select distinct UPPER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(STREET1, '\S+$')) 
from HELENS_DATA 
order by REGEXP_SUBSTR(STREET1, '\S+$') asc
```

Error Message:

> ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression 01791. 00000 - "not a SELECTed expression" *Cause: *Action: Error at Line: 3 Column: 24

Complete Query(works):

```
select distinct UPPER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(STREET1, '\S+$'))
from HELENS_DATA
order by UPPER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(STREET1, '\S+$')) desc;
```

please NOTE that the initial query tried to change the query values to upper by using UPPer() function how ever I have mistakenly ignored the function in the ORDER BY clause and it was not the fault of 'DISTINCT'.

Comment: Please edit your answer to indicate what you've tried that didn't work, and which errors you received exactly in those attempts.

Comment: Please post your **complete query** that works.

Comment: Put `UPPER` in your `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Now it is edited by supplying the working query

Comment: @DilshatAbduwalli - please add your latest edit as an answer. You can then accept the answer to close the question. This will let people know not to try to answer your question.

Comment: due to the lack of reps I cannot answer my own question for 8 hours and now I have to wait another 5 hours to answer

Comment: @DilshatAbduwalli : here is the working version of your query. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/77aec/5 Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's interesting that `DISTINCT` fails when you have the `UPPER` function in place.  You can try to get around it using a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Ending
FROM (select upper(regexp_substr(street1, '\S+$')) Ending) A
```

The subquery really shouldn't be necessary though, this should work too, as chue x recommended.

```
SELECT DISTINCT upper(regexp_substr(street1, '\S+$'))
```

Comment: cool sub query works, it is strange for me as well but thanks for the help

Comment: @DilshatAbduwalli, glad I could help.  So how about a +1 and marking as answer?

Answer (score 1):

`distinct` always comes right after `select`:

```
select distinct upper...
```

Comment: I have tried that, but the oracle has given me error by saying not SELECTed expression

Comment: if I take the upper function off it works but I need to change the values to upper case

Comment: @DilshatAbduwalli - interesting. Sorry, I don't know why `distinct` would fail with `upper`.

Comment: @Dilshat Abduwalli - Please provide the exact query you tried and the complete Oracle's error message.

Comment: Query: select distinct UPPER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(STREET1, '\S+$'))
from HELENS_DATA
order by REGEXP_SUBSTR(STREET1, '\S+$') asc

Comment: ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression
01791. 00000 -  "not a SELECTed expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 24

Comment: I think I found my mistake, it is in the order by clause. because I have tried to upper in the select clause and I did not upper the order by clause, after I have uppered the function in the order by clause i works fin again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

SELECT DISTINCT upper(...) AS 'Field Name'

If you name the field that you are performing this to that may work and allow you to use DISTINCT.

Comment: What does `field alias` has to do with the issue at hand?

Answer (score 0):

To Finalise:

Initially I have run the code in the oracle database as the following code

Complete Query(error):

```
select distinct UPPER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(STREET1, '\S+$')) 
from HELENS_DATA 
order by REGEXP_SUBSTR(STREET1, '\S+$') asc;
```

And as a result I have received the following error message:

```
ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression 01791. 00000 - "not a SELECTed expression"  
*Cause: *Action: Error at Line: 3 Column: 24
```

The answers above helped me to find out the mistake that I have overlooked and the following code is the completed SQL Query which is working fine.

Complete Query(works):

```
select distinct UPPER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(STREET1, '\S+$'))
from HELENS_DATA
order by UPPER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(STREET1, '\S+$')) desc;
```

please NOTE that the initial query tried to change the query values to upper by using UPPer() function how ever I have mistakenly ignored the function in the ORDER BY clause and it was not the fault of 'DISTINCT'.

Conlusion is that whatever argument the SELECT clause has, the other potential clauses, e.g. WHERE, ORDER BY ... etc. should also have the same pattern or same value.

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to repeat the code in the `ORDER BY` clause. Whatever alias you define in the `SELECT` list, can be used in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    UPPER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(street1, '\S+$'))  AS street1_upper 
FROM
    HELENS_DATA
ORDER BY
    street1_upper DESC;
```